# Yii2 migration problems

Tags: php, migration, yii2

I am using yii2 for the first time, and I wanna trying yii migrations.
The problem:
I created migration file with

`php yii migrate/create new_table`

file is created. then I input new table details into migration file.
and when I run `php yii migrate`
I got error

`Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class db does not exist'

in /var/www/yii2.uz/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:415`

what's the problem?

my `console/config/main.php`:

```
<?php 
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
    ); 
    return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
    ];
```

and my migration file:

```
<?php use yii\db\Schema;
      use yii\db\Migration;

      class m150727_125205_new_table extends Migration
      {
       public function up()
      {
        $this->createTable('test',[
           'id'=> Schema::TYPE_PK,
            'name'=>  Schema::TYPE_STRING
        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        echo "m150727_125205_new_table cannot be reverted.\n";

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please add created migration content and console config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DB component setup for console is missing, add this to `console/config/main-local.php` file for local development:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],
```

For production server correct this file according to db settings.

Note that `-local` files are in `.gitignore` list.

Comment: @Faradox check you've written all the params right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the advanced app, you should put the following code in `environment/dev/common/main-local.php` to declare the `db` component in your application:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],
```

If you want the configuration to actually be applied to the application in the advanced template, you should run `./yii init` or `php yii init` command.

If you're using the basic application, you should put it in `common/main-local.php` directly.

It's important to put it under common, not just console, as you'll probably use the same database from both, the console and the web applications.