# yii migration does not working in yii2

Tags: yii, migration

i created yii2 project. When i type yii migrate commant it shows following error:
    Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class db does not exist'

```
in C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
i\Container.php:422                                                         

Stack trace:                                                                
#0 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
i\Container.php(422): ReflectionClass->__construct('db')                    
#1 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
i\Container.php(362): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('db')               
#2 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
i\Container.php(154): yii\di\Container->build('db', Array, Array)           
#3 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
i\Instance.php(157): yii\di\Container->get('db')                            
#4 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
i\Instance.php(131): yii\di\Instance->get(NULL)                             
#5 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
onsole\controllers\MigrateController.php(152): yii\di\Instance::ensure('db',
yii\\db\\Connecti...')                                                      
#6 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
ase\Controller.php(152): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->beforeAc
on(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))                                           
#7 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
onsole\Controller.php(119): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)       
#8 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
ase\Module.php(454): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)           
#9 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii2
onsole\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate', Array)   
#10 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii
console\Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate', 
ray)                                                                        
#11 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\vendor\yiisoft\yii
base\Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii
onsole\Request))                                                            
#12 C:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber\yii(27): yii\base\
plication->run()                                                            
#13 {main}                                                                  

c:\OpenServer\domains\chamber_development\yii2chamber>
```

Please, help me

Answer (score 1):

[Yii2 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31675533/2492110)

DB component setup for console is missing, add this to console/config/main-local.php file for local development:

`'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],`

For production server correct this file according to db settings.

Note that `-local` files are in `.gitignore` list.

Comment: Hi, i have created seperate db.php file containing the same code as stated above.

Comment: '<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2advanced',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
];'

Comment: How, can i connect it to common/config/main-local.php file\

Comment: In your config/web.php or main-local.php file `<?php $params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'); $config = [ 'id' => 'basic', 'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__), // ... // Other config // ... 'components' => [ 'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'), // DB config ], 'params' => $params, ]; return $config;`